# How use java.time.LocalDate using Hibernate5 and Vaadin8?

Tags: maven, java-8, hibernate-5.x, vaadin8

I'm new on Vaadin and I'm trying to do a simple crud application.
I was starting from Vaadin CRUD sample; then I modify the backend project to use Hibernate and the ui project to manage the various tables.
I can do that for simple data type like varchar and int, now I would add a date's field but it returns me this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x07\x03\x00\x00\x07\xE1\x06\x1Ax' for column 'data_nascita' at row 1

"DATA_NASCITA" is a date column on my mysql DB and the entity has a LocalDate linked to this field.

I found somewhere that this new java api is compatible only with Hibernate5 so in my pom file I add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and into the entity class I replace java.util.Date with java.time.LocalDate and delete the annotation @temporal.
The input class for this field is a DateField  of Vaadin framework.

Which could be the problem?

P.S.: I'm blind, so I'm compiling the code with Netbeans8 but I modify the code with notepad++ so, if someone use the same technologies and hasn't any problem please tell me because I can't be sure that the problem is something with build process.

Comment: What type is your `DATA_NASCITA`column in the DB and did you get the chance to go over [this article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/)?

Comment: btw `jpa 2.2` spec includes this *in the default* specification

Comment: @morfic the data_nascita is a date field; I read already the article that you linked but, as said into the answer received, from hibernate5.2 the java8 implementation is into 5.2 core!

Comment: @eugene can you tell me if I can add this specs into maven? Yesterday I looked for that but it seems that jpa2.2 isn't already released!

Comment: @Filippo1980 you are right, not yet released. my point was that when it is released and hibernate will be `2.2` compliant,  there will no need for any additional dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** your hibernate version is greater than `5.2.+` you can just using column as below:

```
@Column
private LocalDate date;
```

**Otherwise** you need install [hibernate-java8](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hibernate-java8%22) module into your project.

On the other hand, you shouldn't install [hibernate-java8](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hibernate-java8%22) module into your project if the hibernate version >= `5.2`, maybe it will makes some conflict, since the [hibernate-java8](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hibernate-java8%22) module is merged into hibernate.

Comment: @holy-java thank you for your answer! Now there is another problem caused by using two different softwares to develop this app, this morning, after the modify of my pom.xml file, Netbeans returned this error: [mypackage].HibernateUtil.java cannot find symbol   symbol:   class AnnotationConfiguration
  location: package org.hibernate.cfg

Comment: @Filippo1980 hi,[AnnotationConfiguration](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.java#AnnotationConfiguration) is removed from hibernate-5. you can try the second solution down the hibernate to `4.3.10` and using `hibernate-java8`. but I'm not sure it can work fine.

Comment: I resolved rewriting HibernateUtil to use registry and metadata.